# Access diskpart.exe in C# class

Tags: c#, process, win32exception

I got error `win32exception was unhandled` using this in class on this part

```
Process dip = new Process();
dip.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\diskpart.exe";
dip.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
dip.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
dip.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
dip.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
dip.Start();
dip.StandardInput.WriteLine("list disk");
dip.StandardInput.Flush();
dip.StandardInput.Close();
dip.WaitForExit();
```

on `dip.Start();` program paused and i saw that error. how can i fix this?
please help!

Comment: If your intention is to mimic the command `C:\Windows\System32\diskpart.exe list disk` you should put the `list disk` into an [Argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments?view=netcore-3.1) instead of trying to use StandardInput.

Comment: even if i make list disk command it doesn't start the diskpart.exe

Comment: what exactly is message with the win32exception ? diskpart requires administrative access... are you running your program as admin?

Comment: yes my program runs as admin

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What is your ultimate goal? I suspect a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here.